# How to perform string interpolation in angular/typescript to access value from within a variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, string-interpolation

I have a variable, such as:

> demoVars:any[];

which has 3 further properties, var1, var2, var3.

> demoArr=[];

Now, in my component class, I have a variable `'selectedVar'` which is equal to the name of one of the property; `var1`, `var2`, or `var3`.

Now I want to achieve:

> for( const demoVar of this.demoVars)
> this.demoArr.push(demoVar.var1);

OR

> for( const demoVar of this.demoVars)
> this.demoArr.push(demoVar.var2);

OR

> for( const demoVar of this.demoVars)
> this.demoArr.push(demoVar.var3);

depending on the value of selectedVar.

if i use:

> for( const demoVar of this.demoVars)
> this.demoArr.push(`demoVar.${this.selectedVar}`);

it pushes the string instead of value;

I want to do something like

> for( const demoVar of this.demoVars)
> this.demoArr.push(demoVar.`${this.selectedVar}`);

What's the right syntax for this, or what's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bracket notation:

```
for( const demoVar of this.demoVars) {
    this.demoArr.push(demoVar[this.selectedVar]);
}
```

For extra safety, you can check if object has such property:

```
for( const demoVar of this.demoVars) {
    if (demoVar.hasOwnProperty(this.selectedVar)) {
        this.demoArr.push(demoVar[this.selectedVar]);
    }
}
```